# .htaccess redirect https://domain1.com to https://domain2.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

We have domain.com and domain.com.au pointing to the same website and currently have the following in our .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com\.au$ [NC]  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is semi working to redirect all requests for the site to the correct secured url.

The only issue is when we go to https://domain.com we are always warned by the browser first that the page may be insecure - if we accept the warning then the page correctly redirects to https://www.domain.com.au.

Is there some way to prevent this warning prior to the redirection of the correct secured domain or should we have the .htaccess redirection written differently?

Comment: The only way to prevent that would be to (1) Configure a different virtual host for that domain, preferably on it's own IP (see [this link for a short explanation why](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts)). (2) Configure that host with a valid SSL certificate (3) still do your redirects.

Comment: Thanks for that reference link - makes sense now.